# Calling Controller Class and passing value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a menu using `<ui><li></li></ui>` tags. I am reading from an XML file and storing it in a List of(menu) object.

***Menu Object:***

```
Public Class MenuVM

#Region "Properties"
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Comments As String
    Public Property UserControlName As String
    Public Property AssemblyName As String
    Public Property ModelName As String
    Public Property SortOrder As Integer
    Public Property IsSelected As Boolean
#End Region

End Class
```

***HomeController Class:***

```
    Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller


    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim oMenuHelper As New MenuHelper
        Return View("index", oMenuHelper.BuildMenu())
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function Index(ByVal iSelect As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim oMenuHelper As New MenuHelper
        Return View("index", oMenuHelper.BuildMenu())
    End Function

    Function About() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
End Class
```

***ASPX PAGE:***

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of List(OF MVCApp.MenuVM))" %>
<%@ Import Namespace ="MVCApp" %>
<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="menu" class="block"> 
    <% Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")%>  
      <ul id="menuItems"> 

        <% For Each item As MVCApp.MenuVM In Model%>
         <li><%: Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Index", "Home", New With {item.ID}, Nothing)%></li>               
        <%Next%>
       </ul> 
        <% End Using %>              

</div> 
</asp:Content>
```

The output:

[image]

When You click on view source the output is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>

    Home Page

</title><link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">


        [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]

            </div> 
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">


    <div id="menu" class="block"> 
    <form action="/" method="post">  
      <ul id="menuItems"> 


         <li><a href="/Home/Index/1">Ballot Language</a></li>               

         <li><a href="/Home/Index/2">Assisting Absentee Voter</a></li>               

         <li><a href="/Home/Index/3">Instructions</a></li>               

         <li><a href="/Home/Index/4">Ballot Questions</a></li>               

       </ul> 
        </form>              

</div> 

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ERROR: When I Click on the link I am getting following error:

[image]

Could any one help with it. My intension is to pass menu id to controller and load appropriate usercontrol. I cannot use Javascript or jquery in this project as user might have javascript disabled on machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove "controller" word from the links. The url should be:"/Home/Index/1".
To do so, modify the ActionLink code:

```
Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Index", "Home", New With {item.ID}, Nothing)%>
```

Comment: It doesn't executes the controller Post method().

Comment: The <a href="..." /> doesn't execute the POST....it generates a GET. To make a POST you have to use a <form action=".." or Jquery.

Comment: can you give an eample of form action tag

Comment: `<% Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")%>`

Comment: Why does it need to be a post.  Are you changing data on the server side?

Comment: Yes. I have to load an Usercontrol according to the selection of menu. I can't use javascript or Jquery.

Comment: Can u suggest any other control or way which would help me execute a post and use as a menu also.

Comment: you are on the wrong way. You shouldn't use a post in this context. Remove the filter on the Index Action and go on with the ActionLink.

Comment: I would agree that the ActionLink is the preferred way for producing the links rather than hard coding them in.

Comment: How will I determine which menu item was selected.

Comment: in the index action you will get the id of the selected menu

Comment: In the above senario the get action will be executed whennever user tries to select a menu link. how will I get to know which menu was selected?

Comment: Actually I figured it out by using ControllerContext.RouteData.Values Thanks ema for your help appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the link as /Home/Index/1 not /HomeController/Index/1